# How can I full-screen a Facebook canvas game?

Tags: html-canvas, viewport, facebook

Is there any way to allow the user to click a button on a Facebook canvas app and allow the app to go full-screen?

If it's possible, is it permitted by Facebook?

Answer (score 2):

Sure!

The web has a "request fullscreen" API that you can use (be sure to read up on in the reference section below). Facebook seems to indicate this is allowed to be use, just take a [look at this transcript](https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/436162913102704?browse=search_5046c9a1032a58d19137888):

> Now that Facebook is crippling Facebook Connect powered games as of
>   December 5, 2012 it is imperative that the allowFullScreen attribute
>   is added to Canvas apps' iframes so that we can utilize HTML5's
>   fullscreen mode in our games.

Then, some time later...

> This should now be resolved. Thanks for your patience.

**Requesting Fullscreen**

Simply retrieve your canvas element and call *requestFullScreen*:

```
(document.getElementById('canvas')).requestFullscreen();
```